# RegEX : Parsing text for exact string match or same string with underscore at the end

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse a text file in PHP and group the content based on string match.

Text sample:

xxxx xxxx xx xxxx xxx **foo** xxx xxx xxxxx

xxxx xx **foo** xxx xxx xxxxx

xx xxxxx xxxx xx xxx xx **bar** xx xxxx

xxxxxx xx xxxxx x xxxx **bar**

xxx xxxxx xx xx **foo_sub1** xxx xxxx

xx **foo_sub2** xxxxx xxx x xxxx

xxx xx **foo1_sub1** xxx xxxx

xxxxx **foo1_sub2** xxxxx xxx x xxxx

```
private function stringContains ($string, $substring){
    if (preg_match("~\b$substring\b~", $string)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

the problem is that if the substring is foo it will not return me foo_sub, any idea how to edit my regex to include any foo and foo_ but not foo1 or foo1_?

Thanks,

Comment: I think `\bfoo(_.*?)?\b` may do it (but not a regex expert)

Comment: you sir may not be a regex expert but it worked ! :) thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\bfoo(?:_\w+)?\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mw4eA9/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `foo` - some fixed value
- `(?:_\w+)?` - an optional part:

  - `_` a `_`
  - `\w+` -  one or more letters, digits or `_` chars
- `\b` - word boundary

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/gPjD3):

```
$str = 'xxxx xxxx xx xxxx xxx foo xxx xxx xxxxx\nxxxx xx foo xxx xxx xxxxx\nxx xxxxx xxxx xx xxx xx bar xx xxxx\nxxxxxx xx xxxxx x xxxx bar\nxxx xxxxx xx xx foo_sub1 xxx xxxx\nxx foo_sub2 xxxxx xxx x xxxx\nxxx xx foo1_sub1 xxx xxxx\nxxxxx foo1_sub2 xxxxx xxx x xxxx';
if (preg_match_all('~\bfoo(?:_\w+)?\b~', $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => foo
    [2] => foo_sub1
    [3] => foo_sub2
)
```

Comment: A bit more precise than Nigel but thanks. I would love to be able to speak your language guys :). One day I'll get to learn regex. Any good material you would suggest ?

Comment: @Izanatos I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.